# which account does MSDE execute under?

Tags: account, msde

have a .net app that talks to a locally hosted MSDE instance -does anyone know the user account the MSDE runs under?

The business sysadmins have released a bunch of "upgrades" to PC's (apparently for active directory and a bunch of other stuff) and now the app cannot connect to the database - so we figure the user account may have been deleted.
Buzz

Answer (score 0):

MSDE - I haven't come across that in a while, that dates back to SQL Server 2000! (MSDE was replaced with SQL Server Express in 2005, so you're a bit out of date).

Anyway, MSDE runs as an NT service, and every service (at least up to Windows Vista) runs under a user account: often one of SYSTEM, NetworkService, or LocalService (Windows 7 and later introduces the concept of Service Identities, which is complicated). You can also run a service under its own user identity, which can be a built-in principal like SYSTEM, a local user account, or a domain account.

I've forgotten the defaults that MSDE uses, but considering it was made in 1999/2000 before NetworkService was invented, it probably runs under SYSTEM or LocalService. To be sure, check your `Services.msc` listing.

As for the failure-to-connect, that could be caused by anything: firewall, configuration error, etc, not just a wrong service identity.

So anyway, check your `services.msc` and your Application Event Log, then report back with your findings.

Comment: Ahh i found out the problem. The Desktop Environment was changed by the Desktop nerds and the computer names were all changed from "mycomputername" to "mycomputername.something.else.com"  and the DB code doesnt like the second. So parsed out after the first '.' and it fixed it